# Xcode: Edit > Refactor > Rename says "Operation couldn’t be completed. File exists."

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode5.1

I have been using `Edit > Refactor > Rename` to rename my classes in xcode. This was all going fine until during one of the refactors xcode froze. I waited for ten minutes and finally just forced xcode to quit.

So I reopened xcode, and went to `File > Restore Snapshot`, and restored the snapshot taken right before the refactor. This worked perfectly.

Here's where I run into a problem. When I go to refactor the name for this class again, it gets to the preview stage with side by side file comparison, but when I click `Save` I get an error of:

> Operation couldn’t be completed. File exists.

What's strange is that after the rename fails, if I go and look in my class's header and implementation files, the class name has been changed. However, when I look in the Project Navigator, my files still have the old name.

Also, the class files in my actual desktop folder for the app show that the class file names are still the same.

I just want to make sure that the rename has fully happened, and need the class file names to reflect the change as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked through my app's system folder again, and the renamed files were there. Not sure what happened, but must be because xcode froze during the refactor.